# Liquibase insert JSON data

Tags: json, liquibase

What is the best way to insert a big `JSON` data using `Liquibase`?

So I have a big `JSON` data that I need to insert the database using Liquibase, how can I achieve that? I make my changes using `xml` format.

`loadData` only supports csv file.

Comment: did you figure out how after all these year?

Comment: @Fredou not the best way but embedded json into CSV (may need to skip especial characters)

Answer (score 1):

If you can convert json to csv, you can use change-set to import data from csv file.

```
    <changeSet id="1" author="author1">
        <loadData file="db/changelog/test.csv" separator=";" tableName="table-name">
        </loadData>
    </changeSet>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I'd love to see a JSON change type but writing one is a substantial undertaking and not suitable when a simple upstream JSON -> CSV conversion will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

The ***best*** way to do this would be to write a new custom change type, but if you don't want to do that the second best way would be to use the `sqlFile` change type.

Comment: Please provide some guidance on both methods